# how to achieve `stack run --file-watch`

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I work with Haskell stack and found the `--file-watch` opton, but was then surprised that it works for `build` but not for `run`. Searching on the web indicates that there are some ways to achieve the effects of `stack run --file-watch`  with other commands (`script`?), but I could not find a simple, straightforward solution. Is there one?

Answer (score 5):

Use `--exec COMMAND [ARGUMENT(S)]` for `stack build`

From `stack build --help`:

```
--exec COMMAND [ARGUMENT(S)]

Command and argument(s) to run after a successful build
```

So, finally

```
stack build --file-watch --exec COMMAND
```

The name of executable file is specified in package.yaml (or .cabal)